# is there an abnormal way to terminate a child process to get certain outputs in this code?

Tags: operating-system, parent-child, pid, terminate, waitpid

i'm new to operating systems and i found this code , and i don't understand why certain outputs like : abc , we can't get
suppose we have this code in c :

```
    int main() 
{
    if(fork()==0)
        printf("a");
        else
        {
            printf("b");
            waitpid(-1);
        }
        printf("c");
    return 0;
}
```

waitpid() waits for a child process to terminate.
can the child process be terminated in abnormal way ? so that we can have this outputs : abc, bc ?

Answer (score 0):

according to at least the linux manpage for `fork`:

```
RETURN VALUE
       On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent, and
       0  is returned in the child.  On failure, -1 is returned in the parent,
       no child process is created, and errno is set appropriately.
```

so if your child program isn't ever created the entire output will be `c` for the parent process and nothing for the child process, because it never came to be.

Also it is possible that the parent process is killed before it can output `a`, or `c`, then you'll only get the child's output, `bc`. or maybe the parent is killed before it can even fork! there are lots of possibilities and with good timing (and some calls to the `sleep` function inbetween) you could probably reproduce them.